# How to initialize player.fadeIn with a variable using Tone.JS?

Tags: typescript, audio, web-audio-api, tonejs

- My project is playing a piece of audio using tone js and i want to use player.fadeIn to fade the audio in from the beginning.
- my goal is to just have a variable to control the fade duration of the player.
- any help on this is greatly appreciated thanks :)
- The functionality was successful when hardcoding the value as written below. This would fade the audio in with a duration of 5 seconds.

  - ```
    player.fadeIn = 5;
    ```
- When I tried to use a variable to represent the fade duration as written below, I would get the following error.

  - ```
    player.fadeIn = fadeDuration
    ```
  - ERROR:

    ```
    Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Time'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Time'.
    ```
- and if i tried changing the type of fade duration variable to type 'Time' a similar error is presented.

  - ERROR:

    ```
    Type 'Time | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Time'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Time'.
    ```

Comment: How do you define `fadeDuration` ?

Comment: its defined as a number

Comment: And where do you assign your value to `fadeDuration`?